# A string between a BETWEEN function on SQL doesn't inclusive

Tags: php, sql-server

I have 120 data on my database and my target is on the `tanggal` column, they're all have a `VARCHAR datatype`. Most of them has `'04/12/2017'` values and I already inserted a value to trigger the data which has `'20/11/2017'` and `20/12/2017'` value.

I want to pick the data using `BETWEEN` function but when I run the query it's only shows the date I mentioned on the between function.

All of the `'04/12/2017'` value doesn't appear on the result.

Why this is happen ? please help..

This is my code :

```
//filter query
$tanggal            = $_POST['tanggal'];
$jenis_pelanggaran  = $_POST['jenis-pelanggaran'];
$lokasi_outlet      = $_POST['lokasi-pelanggaran'];
$pelanggar          = $_POST['pelanggar'];
$lastmonth          = "20/".date("m/Y", strtotime("-1 months"));
$now                = "20/".date("m/Y");
echo $lastmonth . "<br>" . $now;

// Define and execute the query.
// Note that the query is executed with a "scrollable" cursor.
$sql = "SELECT
            dbo.pelanggaran.id_pelanggaran,
            dbo.pelanggaran.tanggal,
            dbo.pelanggaran.waktu_pelanggaran,
            dbo.pelanggaran.nama_pelanggar,
            dbo.pelanggaran.bukti_screenshot,
            dbo.pelanggaran.bukti_rekaman,
            dbo.pelanggaran.bukti_dokumen,
            dbo.jenis_pelanggaran.pelanggaran,
            dbo.jenis_pelanggaran.j_denda,
            dbo.daftar_outlet.nama_outlet
            FROM
            dbo.pelanggaran
            INNER JOIN dbo.jenis_pelanggaran ON dbo.pelanggaran.id_jenis_pelanggaran = dbo.jenis_pelanggaran.id
            INNER JOIN dbo.daftar_outlet ON dbo.pelanggaran.id_lokasi_outlet = dbo.daftar_outlet.id

            WHERE
            dbo.pelanggaran.tanggal BETWEEN '$lastmonth' AND '$now'
            AND
            dbo.pelanggaran.nama_pelanggar LIKE '%$pelanggar%'
            AND
            dbo.daftar_outlet.nama_outlet LIKE '%$lokasi_outlet%'
            AND
            dbo.jenis_pelanggaran.pelanggaran LIKE '%$jenis_pelanggaran%' ORDER BY tanggal DESC";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));
if ( !$stmt )
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
```

Comment: Guh, dates where the DAY is shown first. I just toss everything into the database as an int (timestamp). Far less fiddly, and if I ever need to output it visually, then php's `date()` does its job without even more fiddly.

Comment: The problem here is not your query, it is that you decided to store dates as character data. Don't do this!!!

Comment: but when I set the datatype as `date` and trying to show the data it shows an error, sir. `Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string`

even my code is not in OOP style.

Answer (score 2):

Don't store dates in strings, it's a recipe for this very disaster

Store dates in dates, and this won't happen

If you're adamant that you want to store dates in strings, store them in YYYYMMDD format, so that they sort correctly, and at least nuisance effects like this won't occur (you'll just have poor performance in other areas and difficulties working with the dates as strings for any kind of math operations like working out how many days ago a date was)

"04/12/2017" is NOT between "20/11/2017" and "20/12/2017" any more than "elephant" is between "hello" and "goodbye"

Think strongly-typed, not stringly-typed :)

Comment: Your hat is upside down. `:I`

Comment: I'm Australian; it's all upside down :)

Answer (score 0):

They are character strings, not date strings.  If you don't think of them as a date, it is pretty easy to see why they are not sorting as you expect.

```
0412
2011
2012
```

0412 is obviously not between 2011 and 2012.  Not also that since they are character strings, 0412 is also not between 410 and 415, but it is between 0410 and 0415.  I hope that helps.

When stored as strings, dates and times [and numbers] lose their meaning and can also have incorrect values added.  13/13/2017 is a perfectly valid string, but will throw an invalid date error no matter what region you are in.